# Bash: how to interrupt this script when there's a CTRL-C?

Tags: bash, interrupt, copy-paste

I wrote a tiny Bash script to find all the Mercurial changesets (starting from the tip) that contains the string passed in argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

CNT=$(hg tip | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -c 3)
while [ $CNT -gt 0 ]
do
    echo rev $CNT
    hg log -v -r$CNT | grep $1       
    let CNT=CNT-1
done
```

If I interrupt it by hitting ctrl-c, more often than not the command currently executed is "hg log" and it's that command that gets interrupted, but then my script continues.

I was then thinking of checking the return status of "hg log", but because I'm piping it into grep I'm not too sure as to how to go about it...

How should I go about exiting this script when it is interrupted? (btw I don't know if that script is good at all for what I want to do but it does the job and anyway I'm interested in the "interrupted" issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite your script like this, using the $PIPESTATUS array to check for a failure:

```
#!/bin/bash

CNT=$(hg tip | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -c 3)
while [ $CNT -gt 0 ]
do
    echo rev $CNT
    hg log -v -r$CNT | grep $1
    if [ 0 -ne ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ] ; then
            echo hg failed
            exit
    fi     
    let CNT=CNT-1
done
```

Comment: I should probably point out that both $PIPESTATUS and the pipefail option that Arkku mentioned are Bash version 3+ specific. They're not supported by other shells.

Comment: thanks, on my Debian Linuxes I do indeed have Bash 3+ but on my Macs it's Bash 2.05.

Comment: Really? That's surprising. I'm running bash 3.2.48 on my MacBook Pro, and I don't recall upgrading it myself. What version of OSX are you running?

Comment: Leopard on my MacBook Pro that just had a hard disk crash this morning, so can't check ;)   And 10.4.11 on my Mac Minis (that's the ones that have Bash 2.05), which I need specifically to test because we're shipping apps on 10.4, 10.5 and 10.6 and so we do need these older versions of OS X to test our software.

Answer (score 6):

Place at the beginning of your script: `trap 'echo interrupted; exit' INT`

**Edit:** As noted in comments below, probably doesn't work for the OP's program due to the pipe. The `$PIPESTATUS` solution works, but it might be simpler to set the script to exit if any program in the pipe exits with an error status: `set -e -o pipefail`

Comment: The trap command only works with processes that don't trap interrupts themselves. If the script was receiving the interrupt, it would be aborting itself already.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I missed the pipe in the OP's script. A better answer might be to:

set -e pipefail

Comment: Your first solution (the trap) would work with any process that doesn't trap interrupts itself -- *find* is a good example of a long-running process that will pass through the interrupt, causing the script to abort. The trap can be used to prevent the script from aborting immediately in order to do cleanup, kind of like a destructor or finalizer. It's a handy command to know about.

Comment: That should be `set -o pipefail`.

Comment: Actually, I meant set -e -o pipefail, the -e to make the program script exit on error and -o pipefail to make the pipe fail if hg returns an error status.

Comment: You might not want the script to exit on other errors, though.

Comment: @musiphil If you don't want the script to exit on other errors, simply place the `set -e -o pipefail` just before the pipe you would like it to effect, then unset those options using `set +e +o pipefail` after the pipe you would like to apply it to.

Answer (score 1):

The `$PIPESTATUS` variable will allow you to check the results of every member of the pipe.